# C# как обратиться к обьекту созданному в другом методе в пределах одного класса

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Имеется код windows forms который , по нажатию на "button4" ("Start"), создает новый поток, постоянно принимающий сообщения с COM порта. Вроде все работает, но когда я нажимаю на кнопку "button5" ("Stop"), закрывающий COM порт выкидывается ошибка, и правильно ведь второй поток работает и пытается обратиться к COM порту, а он закрыт. 
Вот я и решил еще и останавливать второй поток нажатием на "button5" ("Stop"). Однако, как это сделать? Знаю что Abort() не приветствуется, но в моем случае это не беда, а хотя если есть способы по интереснее буду вам благодарен если поделитесь.

P.S: **Не читайте это если можете помочь моим же способом слегка подправив его**:
 пытался создать инстанс потока в классе "Form1" а не в методе "button4_Click()", но тогда компилятор требует чтобы метод "readSerial()" был "static", а на это уже ругаются все обращения к объектам внутри этого метода, вобщем я новичок в c# а документация, к новичкам, не особо дружелюбная...

UPDATE:
Для соискателей: Сделал как советовал Сергей, а также по нажатию "button5"("Stop") сперва я закрыл поток, а потом уже COM порт, и ошибки больше не вылетают.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace factyWinDBIntrf01
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            getAvailPorstList();

        }
        //TRIED TO CREATE HERE
        //Thread readingThread = new Thread(readSerial);

        void getAvailPorstList()
        {
            String[] portsList = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            selectCOMPort.Items.AddRange(portsList);
        }

        private void groupBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                textBox1.Text += serialPort1.ReadLine();
                textBox1.Text += "\n";
            }


            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                textBox1.Text = "Receive Timeout";
            }
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //private
        {
            try
            {
                if (selectCOMPort.Text == "")
                {
                    textBox1.Text = "COM Port is not selected";
                }

                else if (comboBox1.Text == "")
                {
                    textBox1.Text = "Baud rate is not set";
                }

                else
                {
                    serialPort1.PortName = selectCOMPort.Text;
                    serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text);
                    serialPort1.Open();
                    progressBar1.Value = 100;
                    textBox1.Enabled = true;
                    textBox2.Enabled = true;
                    button2.Enabled = true;
                    button3.Enabled = true;
                    selectCOMPort.Enabled = false;
                    button4.Enabled = false;
                    button5.Enabled = true;

                    //I need to abort this thread from outside
                    Thread readingThread = new Thread(readSerial);
                    readingThread.Start();
                }
            }

            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            { textBox1.Text = "Unauthorized Access"; }
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            textBox1.Enabled = false;
            textBox2.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = false;
            selectCOMPort.Enabled = true;
            button4.Enabled = true;
            button5.Enabled = false;

            //WANT TO CALL HERE THE "readingThread.Abort();"
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.WriteLine(textBox2.Text);
        }

        void readSerial()
        {
            while (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
                    {
                        textBox1_TextSafe(serialPort1.ReadLine());
                        textBox1_TextSafe("\n");
                        //textBox1.Text += serialPort1.ReadLine();
                        //textBox1.Text += "\n";
                    }
                }

                catch (TimeoutException)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = "Receive Timeout";
                }
                //Tread.Sleep(0);
            }
        }

        delegate void StringArgReturningVoidDelegate(string text);

        private void textBox1_TextSafe(string text)
        {
            if(textBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                StringArgReturningVoidDelegate d = new StringArgReturningVoidDelegate(textBox1_TextSafe);
                Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
                //textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
               // textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
                //textBox1.Refresh();
            }

           else
            {
                textBox1.Text += text;
                //textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
                //textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
                //textBox1.Refresh();
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
            //textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
            //textBox1.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Тут не с документацией проблема, а с теорией

Comment: Вы можете хранить ссылку на объект потока в поле класса. Тогда сможете обращаться к нему из любого метода.

Comment: @ mirypoko вот именно этого ответа мне и надо, только как это сделать не знаю :(

Comment: Ниже уже написал как это сделать. В общих чертах

Comment: Без слез на этот код не взглянешь=( поэтому я напишу наставления 1) Много логики в обработчиках событий. Вынесите их в отдельные именованные методы. 2)Почему контролы называются стандартными именами?

Comment: Я совсем совсем новичок в C# (нужна програмка-интерфейс для моего проекта на c++) и пока не рискнул даже контролы поменять, если вы заметили я помел только самый первый и было страшно когда я решил его еще раз изменить (там зависимость между файлами) поэтому сосредоточился на функциональности в урон архитектуре. Но обязательно учту ваши советы, спасибо вам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я промолчу про все остальное, но проблему можно решить вынеся объект потока в поле класса `Form1`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   private Thread readingThread;
```

Ну и далее по коду обращаться уже к нему. Все потому что вы поток создаете (и объявляете) локально - за пределами той функции его можно сказать и нет для остального кода. Таким образом мы выносим на более высокий уровень этот объект.

Comment: Ох, спасибо , это все мое тугодумство, забыл что объявить можно не присваивая значения. Только вчера начал знакомство с С#, видимо растерялся немного. Спасибо ! :)

Comment: Ура! Все заработало, ошибки больше не выкидывает!! Единственное добавлю для соискателей, что сперва я закрыл поток, а потом уже COM порт, и ошибки больше не вылетают. Спасибо еще раз!